# MySQL Query that only runs within 72 hours

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I currently have a script that runs news, from a game, and displays stats etc.  One of the queries just counts the number of items in the database and displays it.  The database it is counting has a column named "timestamp" and it is in the unix timestamp format (number of seconds).

I want the query only to add up the number of instances in the database that has occurred within the 72hours prior to the query being ran. (so If i run it at 10am 8/8/14 I want it to count the records backwards 72 hours all the way to 10am 8/5/2014).

I've tried to write my query to accomplish this but I do not know enough about how to write queries to figure out how I should arrange it.  Here is what I have so far which counts all records in the entire database regardless of time:

```
$result2 = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(xxxxx) FROM xxx WHERE xxxxx= '$row[3]'")
           or die("Could not select the table");
```

How can I modify the above query to filter out anything that is no within the last 72 hours.  Remember my data base does have a column called "timestamp" which is in the unix timestamp format.  Thanks for the help this has stumped me for a while now!

Answer (score 3):

```
WHERE yourtimefield > (now() - INTERVAL 72 HOUR)
```

Answer (score 1):

If the timestamp field is a proper time column and not an integer, you can use MySQL to do this for you. 72 hours is 3 days. The datediff function returns the number of days between two date/time fields.

```
select * from xxx where datediff(now(),timestamp)<=3;
```

Comment: You should be wary of wrapping a nice indexable timestamp in a function.. this invalidates any index. Also, from the [DATEDIFF](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_datediff) docs; only the date parts of the values are used in the calculation.. so this isn't quite correct.

Comment: The feed I gather the data from includes it as part of the feed so I saved it in my database as an INT.  If I switch that column to a timestamp will mysql recognize it as a timestamp and work?  

Or if I have saved the timestamp as INT is there a way to write the query to still accomplish this?

Comment: @Ryansworld84 switch the column to a `timestamp`, it will work.. maybe create a backup column first if you aren't convinced; also use Marc B's answer.

Comment: Ok I'll try that.  One last question then: the feed I gather the info from includes the timestamp of the occurrence of the event within the game.  If I change that column to timestamp will it keep the time provided by the feed (which is in unix format) or override it as the time I inserted it into my database?

Answer (score 0):

You can get time timestamp with strtotime function

And your code would be like

```
$time = strtotime ("-3 DAY");
$result2 = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(xxxxx) FROM xxx WHERE xxxxx= '$row[3]' AND timestamp > $time")
           or die("Could not select the table");
```

Comment: I think this will work just fine!  My 'timestamp' column isnt stored in a 'timestamp' type in mysql its stored as an INT as it is provided to me from the game server.  Will it still work if that column is an INT but stores a unix format time?  Or do I need to switch that column to a timestamp type on mysql server?

Comment: This will work for a int type column in mysql. You don't need to change column type.